# Array Dynamic resize in heap

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I have answered a Question in Stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55804715/homework-c-problem-involving-arrays-pointers-and-functions).

> a) Create a function called resize that can be used to increase the
>   size of integer arrays dynamically. The function takes three
>   parameters. The first parameter is the original array, the second
>   parameter is the size of this array, and the third parameter is the
>   size of the larger array to be created by this function. Make sure
>   that you allocate memory from the heap inside this function. After
>   allocating memory for the second array the function must copy the
>   elements from the first array into the larger array. Finally, the
>   function must return a pointer to the new array.
>
> b. In main, allocate an array on the heap that is just large enough to
>   store the integers 5, 7, 3, and 1.
>
> c. Resize the array to store 10 integers by calling the resize
>   function created in step a. Remove the old (smaller) array from the
>   heap. Add the numbers 4, 2, and 8 to the end of the new array.
>
> d. Write a sort function that sorts any integer array in increasing
>   order.
>
> e. Use the sort function to sort the array of numbers in c above.
>   Display the sorted numbers.

Is there a Dangling pointer issue.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 

//Bubble Sort
bool sort(int arr[], int size)
{
    for( int i = 0; i< size -1; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < size - i -1; j++)
        {
            //descending order
            if(arr[j]<arr[j+1])
            {
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void Print(int Array[], int nSize)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<" "<<Array[i];
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}

void Resize( int *&Array, const int& nSizeOld, const int& nSize )
{
    int * newArray = new int[nSize];

    //Copy Elements of the Array
    for(int i = 0; i< nSize; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = Array[i];
    }

    delete[] Array;

    //Assign ptr of Prev to new Array
    Array =  newArray;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int kNewSize = 10, kSize = 5;
    int *pMyArray = new int[kSize];

    //Set Values
    for( int i = 0; i< kSize; ++i ) 
    {
        pMyArray[i] = i * 5;
    }

    Resize( pMyArray, kSize, kNewSize );

    //Set Values
    for( int i = kSize; i< kNewSize; ++i ) 
    {
        pMyArray[i] = i * 10;
    }

    Print(pMyArray, kNewSize);

    sort(pMyArray, kNewSize);

    Print(pMyArray, kNewSize);

    if( pMyArray!=NULL )
    {
        delete[] pMyArray;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As Roland Illig points out below, in C++ there's no need to implement your own low level memory management for this when you can just use `std::vector` instead. That said, if you _do_ need/want to implement your own low level array resizing, you should be using [`std::realloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc). The reference page I linked to even provides some (to my inexpert eye) decent example code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you had tagged this code as C, it would have been acceptable. Since you tagged it as C++, it's horrible.

Instead of writing your own `swap` function, there's already `std::swap` in `<algorithm>`.

Instead of writing bubble sort yourself, just use `std::sort`, also from `<algorithm>`.

Instead of using arrays and resizing them yourself, just use `std::vector<int>`, from `<vector>`.

After applying these transformations, you cannot have a dangling pointer anymore since your code is completely pointer-free.

As part of an exercise for learning the basic operations on memory management, it's ok to write code like this, but never ever use such code in production. In production the code should look like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void Print(const std::vector<int> &nums)
{
    for(int num : nums)
    {
        std::cout << " " << num;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums { 5, 7, 3, 1 };

    // There's probably a more elegant way to add the elements to the vector.
    nums.push_back(4);
    nums.push_back(2);
    nums.push_back(8);

    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

    Print(nums);
}
```

By the way, your original code doesn't have any dangling pointer as well. Well done.

You don't need the `!= NULL` check before the `delete[]` since that pointer cannot be null. In modern C++ (since C++11 I think) you would also write `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. The reason is that historically `NULL` had not been guaranteed to be of pointer type.

Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm for more algorithms that you shouldn't implement yourself in C++.

I would have liked to write the `push_back` block in a shorter way, as well as the `Print` function. I'm sure there's a more elegant way, I just don't know it.

Comment: I would just stream char-literals instead of length-one string-literals. And [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) is inho a better reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator I changed the link, thanks for the hint. Regarding the single characters: shouldn't the compiler produce exactly the same code for these two variants by detecting the length 1 string? I thought this was possible in C++. I like code that is as uniform as possible, and using string literals for anything string-like seems simple and nice to me.

Comment: The compiler could in theory inline enough layers to get the same code in the end using whole-program-analysis, necessary due to virtual functions called. I doubt it though.

Comment: "You don't need the != NULL check before the delete[] since that pointer cannot be null" The behaviour is identical anyway, as the `delete` and `delete[]` operators are both defined to be null safe (in which case they do nothing).

Answer (score 4):

The code is obviously wrong: your compiler should have warmed you that `Resize()` never uses its `nSizeOld` parameter.

Comment: That's a funny concept of "wrong"... Anyway, it was probably a typo, since it actually is needed; the question was edited accordingly. This answer is superfluous now.

Comment: Please see *[What to do when someone answers](/help/someone-answers)*. I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1.

Comment: If we follow those rules literally, to correct [what seems to me] a simple typo, OP should ask a completely new question with the fix. Seems kind of ridiculous for such a trivial matter... If every question followed that rule verbatim this site would me a mess. I'm not saying your comment isn't correct or helpful, but it should be precisely that, a comment, so that OP can fix the [irrelevant] issue and move on.

Comment: While your answer is correct and you made a good observation I'd contend that this type of error (a trivial bug) was not what the OP wanted to ask (it would, after all, be OT), so that it does not warrant an answer. I'd have written a comment and waited for the correction. You should imo reinstate the corrected version of the question and delete (or preface as obsolete) your answer.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider As per the rules in the [help/on-topic], all aspects of the code are open to critique. This out-of-bounds memory access bug (which may or may not have been apparent to the author) is absolutely fair game for a Code Review answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your code is too low-level. [It expresses implementation details instead of intent.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p3-express-intent) That's why your code looks like "C with `cout`s instead of `printf` and `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`" instead of C++.
2. [**Roland Illig**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6499/roland-illig) has already told you that you should use `std::swap` instead of building a new one from scratch. [You should use existing libraries, especially the standard library, whenever possible.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p13-use-support-libraries-as-appropriate)

   That said, your own implementation of `swap` is also questionable. This is C++, not C. We have *references*. Using *pointers* makes the code less readable, and puts burden on the user of the function. So you should change it to:

   ```
   void swap(int& x, int& y)
   {
       int temp = x;
       x = y;
       y = temp;
   }
   ```

   And the calls to it can be changed from `swap(&foo, &bar)` to `swap(foo, bar)`. Still, `std::swap` is preferable.
3. Again, [**Roland Illig**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6499/roland-illig) has already told you that you should use the `std::sort` instead of building a new bubble sort from scratch. `std::sort` typically uses [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), which has \$O(n \log n)\$ time complexity; whereas bubble sort has \$O(n^2)\$ time complexity. It should be obvious that `std::sort` is much more efficient.
4. Your parameter lists are *so* C-ish. (pointer, size) parameter pairs are everywhere. [They are error-prone.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f24-use-a-spant-or-a-span_pt-to-designate-a-half-open-sequence) Consider using spans. (Spans are currently not available in the standard library; consider using the one from [GSL](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#gsl-guidelines-support-library))

   You even have parameter lists like `(int*& Array, const int& nSizeOld, const int& nSize)`. Don't pass by const reference for builtin types. Just pass by value, as in `int nSizeOld`, `int nSize`. And letting a pointer denote an array with sizes littered everywhere holds a great welcome party for errors.
5. Don't use `_tmain` and `_TCHAR`. They are not portable. (Strictly speaking, they are not proper C++.) [You should write in ISO standard C++.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p2-write-in-iso-standard-c) Use `main` and `char` instead.

   ```
   // Correct prototype of the main function
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
6. Don't make such liberal use of "naked" `new`s and `delete`s. [Explicit calls to `new`s and `delete`s are very error prone.](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly) `std::vector`s should be preferred from the beginning.
7. You have four `for` loops in total. The first three use `i++`, whereas the last one uses `++i`. Please consistently use `++i`.

As a conclusion: you should refactor your code to express intent.